# How do I chain shape keys?

Tags: workflow, shape-keys

I need to animate a multi step change in a mesh like this

[image]

I set a shape key for the base and then step 2 fine but when I used `new shape key from mix` it applied the transformation for both step 2 and 3.

[image]

How can I get the shape key to only apply changes from step 2 to 3 and not from 1 to 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add two shape keys without the *new shape key from mix* option, you can animate them separately. It is Important is that you keyframe the 2nd part of the animation with influence 0 for the duration of the first part. This way the 2nd part does not start before it is supposed to do.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Editing the shape for extrusion: In *Edit Mode* a loopcut is added at the top of the extruded cube to create the geometry required for the second part of the animation.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to start editing the 3rd shape key starting with the mesh from the 2nd? On yours both keys are modifications of the base shape

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you mean.

Comment: for example if I wanted to extrude from the top end of the part that sticks out I could not do that starting from the default cube because that part of the mesh does not exist yet.

Comment: @Qwertie Now I got it. I simply extruded the top face of the default cube and added a loop cut to create the face which is extruded to the left side. The shape keys work always on a single mesh. Added an image to clarify this.